# regex search and replace for single space in sublime text xml

Tags: xml, regex, search, replace, sublimetext2

I am in Sublime Text 2, trying to replace single spaces within all nodes of an xml doc, so that instances like this:

```
<img>my image title.png</img>
```

will become

```
<img>my%20image%20title.png</img>
```

based on looking around for a while, what I am trying is

```
/(<img>[^ <]*) /\1%20/
```

Which is not working. ANy idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this should work `(?<=\S)(\s)` but it looks for all the spaces. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rI6yA4/9)

Comment: Thanks !! Is the a way just to isolate the spaces inside the <img></img> node?

Answer (score 0):

In **Sublime Text 2** this pattern should work for `<img>my image title.png</img>` or similar:

Find: `(?=</img>|<img>|.)\s`

Replace: `%20`

Result: `<img>my%20image%20title.png</img>`